# Invalid Authenticity Token for rails form with a file

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I'm using UJS to handle a form submit with ajax. The form has a file input in it. I'm getting an invalid authenticity token error from the controller that receives it. Am I forgetting some attribute here either on the form or file tag?

`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

```
<%= form_for @block, 
    remote: true, 
    html: { id: "userInputForm", class: "form" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :something_to_replace %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a [Rails bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22807). To work around it, you have two options:

1. Set `config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true` in your `config/application.rb`
2. Pass the option `authenticity_token: true` to your `form_for`